# Is it a good approach to allow users create a table in MySQL

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I’m developing an inventory system with laravel,users can create categories and get a form dynamically to populate those categories,but I’m having an issue with querying the result into a responsive table cause of the data structure, I have the id, the category id and then the data in categorie_data table, when querying the result I find it difficult using table to make each data for each category stay under there category, it breaks if the user decides to create a new category apart from the old ones created,

so I’m thinking of making the  user create a table directly when creating a inventory/category and populate it his giving data’s that way  it would be easy for me to query, my question is, is it advisable to slow user create a table in the database and is there a better approach that would not involve creating a new table and I would be able to fomat the query result into a table

----------------------------------------------The table---------------------------------------

```
 <table class="table table-striped" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    @foreach  ($categoryDataname as $index => $category)
                        <th scope="col">{{ $category->category_name }}</th>
                        
                       
                        
                        @endforeach
                    <th scope="col">Total</th>
                    <th scope="col">Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <!-- Populate this table with data from your database -->
                
                    <tr >
                            <td>
                               1
                                </td> 
                            
                            @foreach  ($categoryDataname as $category)

                           
                            
                        <td ><div class="div table-responsive color:red">
                           
                                  @foreach($categoryData->where('category_id',$category->id) as $data)
                                     {{ $data->data }}<br/><hr class="position:static"></hr>
                                  @endforeach
                                  
                             </div>
                        </td>
                        @endforeach
                        <td>
                            <!-- Calculate Total -->
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Edit</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
               
                <!-- Add more rows for additional products -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

---------------------the inventory controller -----------------

```
class InventoryController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
{
    $userEmail = Auth::user()->email;
    $categoryData = DB::table('categories')
    ->where('user_email', '=', $userEmail)
    ->get(); 
    
    //return view('inventory.inventory', ['categoryData' => $categoryData]); it value has been returned in below

    $userEmail = auth()->user()->email; // Get the authenticated user's email

    $categoryData2 = CategoryData::whereHas('category', function($query) use ($userEmail) {
        $query->where('user_email', '=', $userEmail);
    })->get();
   


   return view('inventory.inventory', [
    'categoryData' => $categoryData2,
    'categoryDataname' => $categoryData,
   
]);
}

}
```

----------------categorydata model--------------------

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CategoryData extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories_data';
    protected $fillable = ['category_id', 'data']; // List of fillable attributes

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }
}
```

-------------------category model--------------------

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'category_name',
        'user_email',
        // Add any other fields that can be mass assigned here
    ];
public function categoryData()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CategoryData::class, 'category_id');
}
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just have a column with unique values tied to each user and filter by that?

Comment: `it breaks if the user decides to create a new category`...breaks how? You haven't actually shown us an example of the structure or the clear problem. But you shouldn't need to add tables because a user wants to add new data. That is always a symbol of a broken design.

Comment: What exactly does "create a table directly" mean? How can they break anything if you only let them do what you want them to be able do? And why would you let them do anything else?

Comment: [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3579079/3404097) [More](https://stackoverflow.com/q/190296/3404097) [How to design a product table for many kinds of product where each product has many parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/695752/3404097) [More](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2945124/3404097) [And more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5106335/3404097) [Re EAV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23950836/3404097) etc etc etc [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the users, but **I would never trust users to create a table** in a database, as it can cause some failures in your system due to data types and so on.

I've done a **dynamic system** once where I used a structure like this:

- Tables (id, table_name)
- TableFields (id, table_id, is_text, is_numeric, is_boolean, is_date...)
- TableValues (id, field_id, text_value, numeric_value, boolean_value, date_value...)

Feel free to add more field types.

In the TableFields you will basically set the type of the field while in the TableValues, you will store it's value.

Example:

1. User wants to create a table - Stock Inventory
2. User creates two fields - product and quantity

Adding the table

> Insert into Tables (id, table_name) Values (1, Stock);

Adding fields to the table (which in this case is the table with id = 1)

> Insert into TableFields (table_id, field_name, is_text, is_numeric,
> is_boolean, is_date)  Values (1, "Product Name", 1, 0, 0 ,0),
> (1,"Quantity", 0, 1, 0, 0)

Note that I've set is_text to 1 and first insert, and is_numeric to 1 in second insert.

Adding Values to the table

> Insert into TableValues (field_id, text_value, numeric_value,
> boolean_value, date_value) Values (1, "Juice", null, null, null), (2,
> null, 10, null, null)

Like this I've created a table named "Stock" that has two fields (Product Name and Quantity). Then I basically added a row.

- Product Name (field_id 1) - Juice
- Quantity (field_id 2) - 10.

Also note that I've used SQL queries but working on Laravel you should use **[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent)** or **[Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries)**.

Comment: I love this, this is exactly how I did it, but the issues I’m having it querying the result using laravel each category has an Id and also a category_id which is related/same with there category name table, passing out the result come out in an array which makes it difficult to form a table with it, it keep stacking  away  from each other no matter how I try the query cause it queries the result by selecting the category and its data you know all data come along with the array spitting it into <td> is really an issue using foreach in laravel blade

Comment: This needlessly slowly & voluminously reimplements the DBMS.

Comment: @Damsonspecial without a code and data sample no-one would be able to help you with the issue in your html table, it's not described particularly clearly and obviously we can't say what code has caused it. It might be sensible to ask a new question about that separately, being sure to include a [mre] of the issue and also paying attention to [ask]

Comment: i just added the code