# Adding more columns to MySQL table or implode?

Tags: mysql, database-design

My project stores and lists events for a hobby I participate in.

There are "governing bodies" that have organizations as part of their membership (typically region-based), and both the governing organizations and the regional organizations run events (ie. governing = "world championship", regional = qualifier or one-off event).

These events have divisions (Men's, Women's, Boys Under 18, etc.). Most local and/or regional events have maybe 3-5 divisions, but at most, there are some that might have 10. There are ~20 divisions worldwide.

The event table has 14 columns.

Is it better to have 20 additional columns and use something like BOOLEAN to handle when users select to list them out?

Or should I store divisions in a single column, like using arrays, implode/explode, etc.?

I'd like myself/users to sort and filter.

My implementation will be using PHP/JS.

Comment: I would highly recommend reading about database normalisation (for example [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)). Properly normalising your databases now will save you a lot of pain in the future.

Comment: It looks to me that what you need is not more columns, or exploding fields, but more tables. There's not enough detail here to be precise, but anywhere you're thinking of adding additional columns is probably somewhere where you need an additional table. Don't be afraid of tables. Get this right now and life will be a breeze. Get it wrong and you'll condemn yourself to a world of hurt.

Comment: See Bill Karwin's excellent answer to the duplicate questiin that outlines the options for flexible database design in mysql.

Comment: @Shadow this, however, does not apply to boolean values if you wanted to go for best performance, so it's not really a duplicate. See my answer for details.

Comment: [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3579079/3404097) [More](https://stackoverflow.com/q/190296/3404097) [How to design a product table for many kinds of product where each product has many parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/695752/3404097) [More](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2945124/3404097) [And more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5106335/3404097) [Re EAV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23950836/3404097) etc etc etc [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/3404097)

Comment: @volkerschulz yes, Bill's answer apply to any kind of data types, including boolean values.

Comment: Outlining the options, yes. Considering performance, no. Anyways, this question is now marked duplicate, you've made up your mind and I'd rather help other people than fighting over that. ;)

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular - I should have clarified, I already have tables for governing bodies and organizations; I was not intending to simply have one large table. 

I'm not opposed to adding more tables if it helps with entry and retrieval. Most of my past experience with databases has been rudimentary, really only making single-use tables and websites. In terms of a scope that incorporates relational tables, I'm less than a novice and most of the research I've read hasn't been quite so clear.

I appreciate the responses and I will check out the highlighted post.

Answer (score 0):

To store a number of boolean values for each row in a database table, you could

1. Add this number of additional columns to your table (not very flexible, somewhat messy but fast to use in conditionals)
2. Use a relational table for each row with one row for each value inside the relational table, referring to the row in the original table (most flexible, pretty clean, a little bit less performant)
3. Store all values in just one column in your table (can be a performance nightmare when being used in conditionals, depending on how the values are stored)

However, when dealing with boolean values and the number of values is guaranteed to never exceed 64 (on a 64 bit system), option 3 becomes the most performant option, as you could store all the boolean values in just one single (unsigned) integer value, using bitwise operations. For that you're going to assign one single bit to each boolean.

Example:

```
division_1_selected = bit 0 = 1 
division_2_selected = bit 1 = 2
division_3_selected = bit 2 = 4 
division_4_selected = bit 3 = 8
[...]
```

(the value always is 2 to the power of bit_number)

To store a selection you would sum up all values and store the result. If division 1 and 3 were selected, the result would be 5 (1+4). This is the same as using the bitwise OR operator on all division_x_selected.

To retrieve all records for certain selection, you would use the bitwise AND operator. So if you wanted to get all records with divisions 3 and 4 (=12) selected (no matter what the selections for divisions 1 and 2 are), you'd use

```
WHERE col & 12 = 12
```

You do not need to use the bitwise operator when looking for exact matches. So if you wanted to get all rows with division 3 and 4 selected and divisions 1 and 2 unselected, you could simply do

```
WHERE col = 12
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer just repeats part of Bill's excellent answer to the duplicate question. The last option with the bit operators cannot use index for lookup, so may be great for saving data storage space, but will be bad for retrieving the saved data.

Comment: Let's agree to disagree on that one. I've tested with 1,000,000 entries with up to 20 booleans each and the bitwise selection (despite not using indexes) is still faster than a JOIN using indexes on that one. Results may vary... ;)

Comment: What's faster when looking for exact matches is out of question anyways, I suppose.