# Strapi CMS: Dynamically Create Product "Parameter" Fields Based on Related Category

Tags: javascript, typescript, content-management-system, relational-database, strapi

I'm currently working with Strapi CMS and I have a requirement that's been a bit challenging to implement. I need products to have dynamic "parameter" fields which depend on the category they're related to. Essentially, when creating a category, I'd like to define these "parameter" fields for products. Then, when creating or editing products associated with that category, I want to just fill in values for those fields.

For example:

1. If I create a "Mobile Phones" category, I might define parameters like "Battery Life", "Screen Size", and "RAM".
2. When I later add a product to the "Mobile Phones" category, I should have fields to fill in values for "Battery Life", "Screen Size", and "RAM".

Does anyone have experience with such a setup in Strapi or can guide me on how to achieve this?

Thought about using strapi components for parameters, but it might be challenging to ensure data integrity and have a consistent UI. Also there is a lot of product categories in the store.

Comment: [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3579079/3404097) [More](https://stackoverflow.com/q/190296/3404097) [How to design a product table for many kinds of product where each product has many parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/695752/3404097) [More](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2945124/3404097) [And more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5106335/3404097) [Re EAV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23950836/3404097) etc etc etc [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

use postgreSQL, have a field as type object, and save anything you want as object, make sure you do not overwrite it rather update it,

Hope this helps.