# How to model DB tables for multiple optional properties

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

My system has to deliver payloads to multiple types of platforms for example MQTT, AWS S3, TCP IP, etc. And for each of the options i need to store different configuration

- For MQTT I would need the endpoint, topic, username and password
- For AWS S3 I need access key, secret key, region, bucket name and path
- For TCP IP I need IP address and port

Right now I have a table in postgres like:

```
create table public.delivery
(
    id           serial  primary key,
    platform     delivery_platform  not null,
    access_key   varchar,
    secret_key   varchar,
    endpoint     varchar,
    topic        varchar,
    object_name  varchar,
    ip_address   varchar,
    port         integer,
    region       varchar,
    username     varchar,
    password     varchar
);
```

Where delivery_platform is an `Enum` with `MQTT`, `S3` and `TCP` as possible values. And I only populate the corresponding columns. But in the future i might need to add new delivery platforms or more options for each platform. What would be the best way to model this problem?

Comment: In general seems to be fine.

Comment: ip_address sounds like an inet datatype. Varchar and text should only be used when you don't have anything better.

Comment: The `jsonb` datatype is terribly abused judging by questions here, but this is one of the few cases where it might make perfect sense.  I don't know what host language you are using to do the actual delivery, but in Python I would use pydantic to define the different configuration JSON structures.  In Java, I would use Jackson.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3579079/3404097) [More](https://stackoverflow.com/q/190296/3404097) [How to design a product table for many kinds of product where each product has many parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/695752/3404097) [More](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2945124/3404097) [And more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5106335/3404097) [Re EAV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23950836/3404097) etc etc etc [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]