# Different type for InvoiceDetails table

Tags: database, database-design

SaleInvoices table:

| InvoiceId | InvoiceDate | CustomerId |
| --- | --- | --- |

Products table:

| ProductId | ProductCode | ProductName |
| --- | --- | --- |

OtherIncomes table:

| OtherIncomeId | IncomeCode | IncomeName |
| --- | --- | --- |

How can I design a Sale Invoce Details table with different row types for products and other incomes in the invoices?

SaleInvoiceDetails table:

| SaleInvoiceDetailId | SaleInvoiceId | ??????? |
| --- | --- | --- |

Comment: [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3579079/3404097) [More](https://stackoverflow.com/q/190296/3404097) [How to design a product table for many kinds of product where each product has many parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/695752/3404097) [More](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2945124/3404097) [And more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5106335/3404097) [Re EAV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23950836/3404097) etc etc etc [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)  Reflect research in posts.

Comment: There is a bug in the editor: It correctly formats a table that is missing a blank line before it although the published page does not. Click on 'edited' to see what it looked like & how I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, for me I would either :

1. Add another column that functions as foreign key (refers to which reference table the detail info relates to, ie SalesInvoice, Product or OtherIncome)
   or,
2. Use the SalesInvoiceID, ProductID or OtherIncomeID as part of SalesInvoiceDetailID, assuming they are unique to each other.